# ASP.NET MVC get list from controller with ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I search solution for my problem in search engine and stackoverflow.I find a lot of answer but nothing of them didn't help to me.
Here is my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        var cl = new List<Category>();
        cl.Add(new Category()
            {
                Name = "C#"
            });
        cl.Add(new Category()
            {
               Name = "MVC"
            });
        return Json(cl.ToList(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and category class is below:

```
 public class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

In my view,I want to list each item in the data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("Get","Category")',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data: { a: "testing" },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                //<ul>
                     //<li>C#</li>
//<li>MVC</li>
            },
            error: function () { alert('error....'); }
        });
    });

</script>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: And the problem is...? Any errors? What happend if you debug? One thing I do see here is that your are passing a parameter {a:"testing"} and your Get() action don't have one.

Comment: Don't any error.In my view code ,`Succes:function(data) {//}` here data return list.I'd like display this list as `<ul><li></li></ul>`

Comment: In practice developer need special js libraries to establish such situation, for example kendoi ui: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkeBZkqVcrs. Second you must use js for doing it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the shorter `getJSON` like this:

```
var getUrl = '@Url.Action("Get")';
var resultDiv = $('#result');
$.getJSON(getUrl,  data: { a: "testing"},  function (data) {
                                resultDev.append('<ul>')
                                      $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                             resultDiv.append($('<li/>', { text: item.name }));
                                 });
                             });
```

Without seeing your markup I have made the assumption of outputting to a div just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see parameters. I've added them to solution. I'm on an iPhone & can't run it. Let me know if still no good & I will delete answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @hutchonoid. because of you I find solution.I am using your code and update my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("Get","Category")',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data: { a: "testing" },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
               $.each(data, function(index,item) {
                   $("#cat").append('<li>'+item.Name+'</li>');
                });
            },
            error: function () { alert('error....'); }
        });
```

Others are the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
     public JsonResult Get(int userId)
    {
        using (Entities context = new Entities())
        {
            var appNo = context.UserApp.Where(p => p.UserId == userId && p.Status > 0).ToList();
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            appNo.ForEach(p =>
            {
                builder.AppendFormat("<li><a href='https://demos.url.com>{0}</a></li>", p.Id);
            });
            return Json(builder.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dropDownListUser").change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Get", "User", new {Area = "AREANAME"})',
            data: { 'userId': val },
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#ulid').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});</script>

<ul id="ulid"></ul>
```

Comment: Please explain why this answers the question, don't just dump out code